# Error: Unable to serialize object as a key

Tags: gatsby, netlify, host, sanity

I am trying to deploy a Gatsby+Sanity homepage to Netlify. Both the Gatsby homepage and the Sanity CRM is runnig fine locally but I keep getting this error when I try to deploy it online.

[deploy log 1 of 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISRqE.png)

[deploy log 2 of 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtjQX.png)

This is an official build from a the Gatsby developer team. I closely followed their setup steps-https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-sanity-homepage-ts

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. Did you ever get this resolved? I had it working previously, but I think an update might have caused some issues.

Comment: It runs fine for me with `gatsby develop`, but fails with `gatsby build`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, reverting `gatsby-source-sanity` to 7.6.3 resolved the issue. I believe 7.7.0 introduced a bug that affects the starter.